# Group by query producing different results depending on number of calculated fields

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I have a data set containing data on customers per brand and day. That means each customer has one row per brand and day.

| DATE | BRAND | CUSTOMER | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | A | Max | 1 |
| 02.01.2023 | A | Max | 2 |
| 03.01.2023 | A | Max | 3 |
| 04.01.2023 | A | Max | 4 |
| ... | A | Max | .. |
| 31.01.2023 | A | Max | 31 |
| 01.01.2023 | B | Max | 0 |
| 02.01.2023 | B | Max | 1 |
| 03.01.2023 | B | Max | 2 |
| 04.01.2023 | B | Max | 3 |
| ... | B | Max | .. |
| 31.01.2023 | B | Max | 29 |

I want to aggregate this data on YEAR, MONTH, BRAND, CUSTOMER level. I want the last value of the AGE column and count the distinct DATE.  Expecting the folowing output:

| YEAR | MONTH | BRAND | CUSTOMER | LAST_AGE | N_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | A | Max | 31 | 31 |
| 2023 | 1 | B | Max | 29 | 31 |

Therefore I am using the folowing query:

```html
select 
  YEAR
  ,MONTH
  ,BRAND
  ,CUSTOMER
  ,LAST(AGE) as LAST_AGE
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) as N_DAYS
from 
  (select * from data order by BRAND, CUSTOMER, DATE)
group by
  YEAR
  ,MONTH
  ,BRAND
  ,CUSTOMER
```

If I execute the above query in Azure Databricks without `COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE)) as N_DAYS` I receive the correct result. But when I include the second calculation `COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE)) as N_DAYS` the resutls of LAST_AGE change and are wrong. How can that be? Additional calculations should not impact other calculations (when they are independent).
Any pointer towards an answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT DATE)` to make code clearer.

Comment: Expected result that matches the sample data makes sense. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks! @jarlh I corrected the example. And I expected the question for a reproducible example. The point is, when I download the data and implement the same logic in R locally, everything works like it should. The problem only occurs when I run the query on the data in azure databricks.

Comment: Note your sub-query is completely redundant, you should just `select.. from data group by...`

Comment: @Stu you are right. I just added it to make it more clear and exlude unsorted data as a source of error.

Comment: @FAMG adding unecessary or redundant code is not synonymous with clarity - and *ordering* of data is also irrelevant, RDBMS work with sets and sets are by definition unordered; this is a common and critical misconception.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's think, what you have.
You have subquery for ordering:

```
select * from data order by BRAND, CUSTOMER, DATE
```

But, how do this ordering work?
This query order data by BRAND, CUSTOMER and DATE.
How about AGE? Age still be in the random ordering...

Another question - why do you use operatir LAST instead of MAX?
Because everything looks like you do not need the last AGE, you need the max AGE, don't you?

So, as result, you can use two variants:

or add AGE to the order string and just believe, that it will be work

```
select 
  YEAR
  ,MONTH
  ,BRAND
  ,CUSTOMER
  ,LAST(AGE) as LAST_AGE
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) as N_DAYS
from 
  (select * from data order by BRAND, CUSTOMER, AGE)
group by
  YEAR
  ,MONTH
  ,BRAND
  ,CUSTOMER
```

or change operator LAST to operator MAX:

```
select 
  YEAR
  ,MONTH
  ,BRAND
  ,CUSTOMER
  ,MAX(AGE) as MAX_AGE
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) as N_DAYS
from 
  data
group by
  YEAR
  ,MONTH
  ,BRAND
  ,CUSTOMER
```

Comment: @FriednlyDragon thanks for thinking over the problem. But I specifically need the value of the last day per month and not the max. In the example it would be the same but not in my data. 
+ Sorting by Age does not make any sense content wise. That means I want the Age of the last day of the month. It might be the case that Age is high in the beginning of a month and low at the end --> Hence sorting by age and max(age) do not work.

Comment: @FAMG, ok, this is clear. Did you try to use window function? something like this: `LAST(AGE) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR, MONTH, BRAND, CUSTOMER ORDER BY YEAR desc, MONTH desc) AS LAST_AGE`